# How add random numbers to a text file

Tags: python

I am trying to add numbers that are randomly generated into my text file as i read a name from one file into another.
Here is my code:

```
def dogs():
    total_cards = int(input("How many cards do you wish to play with? "))
    N = int(total_cards)
    Y = int(N/2)
    Z = int(N/2)

    with open("dogs.txt") as f:  # Opens needed file
            with open("dogswrite.txt", "w") as f1:  # My own file for player names
                for i in range(Y):
                    line_name = next(f).strip()  # Lists the input number of results each on a new line
                    line_name = line_name + "\n"
                    f1.write(line_name)
                    with open ("dogswritecpu.txt", "w") as f2:  # File for CPU names
                        for i in range(Z):
                            line_name = next(f).strip()
                            line_name = line_name + "\n"
                            f2.write(line_name)
dogs()
```

Currently the dogswrite text file reads with each being on a new line:

```
Molly
Dave
Tim
```

I want to the file to read as

```
Molly, 1 , 30, 48, 100
```

then a new line.
The same happens to Dave and Tim. 
Thanks for all the help.

Class Code:

```
class Dog_card_player: #creates the class
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name
        self.exercise = exercise
        self.friendliness = friendliness
        self.intelligence = intelligence
        self.drool = drool

    def Card_stats_player(self): #creates the stats for the card
        print("Name: " + self.name)
        print("Exercise: " + self.exercise)
        print("Friendliness: " + self.friendliness)
        print("Intelligence: " + self.intelligence)
        print("Drool: " + self.drool)

def Printing_card_player():
    with open ("dogswrite.txt") as f1:
        Dog_name_player = Dog_card_player(f1.readline())
        Dog_name_player.Card_stats_player()
```

Comment: so you want to append 4 random integer at the end of name right ? what should be the range ?

Comment: yes, from 1 to 100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import random

s= ', '.join(str(random.randint(1,100)) for i in range(4))

line_name = 'Molly'
line_name =  line_name+', '+s+"\n"
print(line_name) #  f1.write(line_name)
```

```
Output:
Molly, 42, 37, 39, 43
```

> **random.randint(a, b)** Return a random integer N such that a <= N <= b.
>   Alias for randrange(a, b+1).

What it basically means is that here end is not exclusive if your range is (7,42) both 7 and 42 are inclusive ie they can be part of result.

```
>>> random.randint(0,1)
1
>>> random.randint(0,1)
0
>>> random.randint(0,1)
1
>>> random.randint(0,1)
1
```

don't confuse it with normal range(start, end) that we use with for loop, in which end is exclusive.

```
>>> list(range(0,1))
[0]
>>> list(range(0,2))
[0, 1]
```

> **str.join(iterable)**
>        Return a string which is the concatenation of the strings in iterable. A TypeError will be raised if there are any non-string
>   values in iterable, including bytes objects. The separator between
>   elements is the string providing this method.

Comment: @KithionPrathaban I am glad I could help.

Comment: is there a way i can read the second number  eg 37 in  Molly, 42,37,39,43 while im calling into a class

Comment: what do u mean by calling into class ?

Comment: So i am usiing the lines created in a class under the parameters of name, exercise, friendliness, intelligence and drool but when i call it is proccessed, i get name: Molly, 42,37,39,43. So i am trying to get only Molly out of the line

Comment: maybe you are looking for something like this https://pastebin.com/zgrx6PTk

Comment: Printing_card_player will call Card_stats_player and then you want to readline like for ex:Molly, 42,37,39,43 and fill Name: Molly and so on....

Comment: right ? btw change your `randint(1,101)` to `randint(1,100)` if you don't want 101

Comment: `stats = f1.readline().split(', ')` will give you list at index = 0 you will find name at index = 1 Exercise `self.name = stats[0]`.......